# Put an Indicator inside and EA with Indicator-Only functions in MQL4

Tags: mql4, indicator, forex

So I got a couple of ideas and I'd like to backtest them. And to do so, the indicator must run internally within the EA rather than take its value from the iCustom method. I've got the indicator free from a very nice guy from the internet (obviously...) and I've like to test around with it.

Unfortunately the indicator mentioned is using the OnCalculate function which is only working within indicators and not EAs. So basically copy-pasting code inside EA is really not a option unfortunately.

*Didn't provide code as the problem is a simple as I describe it to keep it short. If you believe this would help, I am more than happy to provide that as well.*

EDIT. Added indicator code:

```
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
{
//---
   int startIndex = MathMax(0, rates_total - prev_calculated - 1);
   
   // Only calculate up until the previous bar. We don't want to calculate the current bar.
   if (startIndex > 0)
   {
      for (int i = startIndex; i >= 1; i--)
      {
         double
            ohlcAvg = (open[i] + high[i] + low[i] + close[i])/4,
            vol = (double) tick_volume[i];

         // Reset values when session changed
         if (TimeDay(time[i]) != TimeDay(__sessionStartTime))
         {
            __sessionStartTime = time[i];
            __ohlcvTotal = 0;
            __volumeTotal = 0;
         }
            
         __ohlcvTotal += ohlcAvg * vol;
         __volumeTotal += vol;
         
         ExtBuffer1[i] = NormalizeDouble(__ohlcvTotal/__volumeTotal, _Digits);
      }
   }
   
   return(rates_total - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can create a custom function within an EA that replicates an indicator by using buffers. I have done this numerous times for clients as it makes the EA a more robust solution when not relying on external indicators.

Example code:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double customIndicator(int IDX, int timeFrame)
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
{
   double   Buffer[1];
   int      buffersize=iBars(Symbol(), timeFrame);
   ArrayResize(Buffer, buffersize);
   ArraySetAsSeries(Buffer, true);

   int pos=buffersize-1;
   while(pos>=0)
   {
      // Indicator calculations
      Buffer[pos]=...
      pos--;
   }

return(buffer[IDX]);
}
```

Comment: By the looks of it. It might work. I will have to try.

Comment: Seemed legit. But I don't think that this would apply on the given indicator.... The tables and the variables that are being assigned by OnCalculate cannot be replicated I think. Edited post and added indicator code to show you what I am talking about.